# How to install dependency BotCore?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I want to open this Project/Solution https://github.com/gorkemhacioglu/Stream-Viewer-Chat-Bot
I cloned it and then opened it using Visual Studio.

But [dependency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBK5a.png) is missing and it gives [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaVmu.png)

I tried to install https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator and I tried to click "Manage NuGet packages for the Solution" and add Microsoft.Bot.Builder but output is like this

> Restoring packages for C:\Users\user\Downloads\Stream-Viewer-Chat-Bot-main\Stream-Viewer-Chat-Bot-main\AutoUpdater\AutoUpdater.csproj...
> Restoring packages for C:\Users\user\Downloads\Stream-Viewer-Chat-Bot-main\Stream-Viewer-Chat-Bot-main\StreamViewerBot\StreamViewerBot.csproj...
> NU1104: Unable to find project 'C:\Users\user\Downloads\Stream-Viewer-Chat-Bot-main\Stream-Viewer-Chat-Bot-main\BotCore\BotCore.csproj'. Check that the project reference is valid and that the project file exists.
> Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'StreamViewerBot'.

and NuGet package Microsoft.Bot.Builder  is not installed

How to install this BotCore dependency ?

Answer (score 0):

From `StreamViewerBot.csproj` file, there’s ProjectReference

```
  <ItemGroup>     
    <ProjectReference Include="..\BotCore\BotCore.csproj" />  
  </ItemGroup>
```

It specifies the path to the referenced project `BotCore`.

Firstly,you should make sure this file is stored in the `BotCore` project in the solution directory .But from your error information, there’s no BotCore.csproj  file in your solution path. Therefore, the project `StreamViewerBot` fails to reference project `BotCore`.

This solution you cloned from github should have 3 project `StreamViewerBot`、`AutoUpdater` and `BotCore`.It obviously the project `BotCore` is missing. Before referencing project `BotCore`,you should clarify the purpose of referencing project according your actual requirements. You can contact the repository auth to ask `BotCore` project code or create your `Botcore` project by your requirements.

For example:

[image]